# MongoDB C# - .First() predicate not working in a projection

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a document like this:

`{ 
  "parent1" : "foo",
  "parent2" : "bar",
  "parent3" : "ignore",
  "parent4" : "ignore",
   "Items": [{
      "numbers": [
         "item1" : "abc",
         "item2" : 123457,
         "item3" : "def"
      ]
    }, {
      "numbers": [
          "item1" : "abc",
          "item2" : 234568,
          "item3" : "def",
       ]
    }, {
       "numbers": [
          "item1" : "abc",
          "item2" : 999998,
          "item3" : "def"
       ]
    }]
}`

I want to be able to query against the fields `.parent1`, `.parent2` and find the first matching value of the child `item2` in the `.Items` array.  I then want to flatten these into a projection so I can sort on that first matching item from the child array (which I have called `Instance` in the projection).

So for a search value of >= 230000, the resulting match would look something like this:

`{
   "Parent1": "foo",
   "Parent2": "bar",
   "Instance": "234567"
}`

In using LINQ with the C# MongoDB driver (asp.net core), I tried something like this:

```
// Query stage (Works)
var query = collection.ToQueryable<T>().Where(x => x.parent1 == "foo" &&
         && x.parent2 == "bar" && x.Items.Any(y => y.numbers.item2 >= 230000));

// Projection (Doesn't work)
var projection = query.AsQueryable().Select(x => new Output()
{
  Parent1 = x.parent1,
  Parent2 = x.parent2,
  Instance = x.Items.First(y => y.numbers.item2 >= 230000).item2,
});

// Sort and get results (Would work if the projection above did)
var result = projection.OrderBy(x => x.Instance).ToList();
```

The problem I have is that the `First` predicate is being ignored in the projection and so the value coming back is `0`, rendering the sorting stage useless (and giving me bad results).

Is there an alternate way to acheive the same thing in LINQ or is there a way to acheive this using the C# MongoDB Builder objects?

Comment: Don't store numbers as strings.  Store numbers as numbers.  "5" is greater than "230000" and "10000000000" is *less* than "230000".

Comment: This was just to exemplify my issue. I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at the MongoDB driver source, I was able to ascertain that the .First() predicate will fire correctly, it's the use of an individual field on the resulting item that is the problem (the driver appears to omit the predicate entirely in this case, which is why it yields a '0').

To work around this limitation, the solution is to project the entire result of the .First() predicate (instead of just the desired property) and then change the subsequent .OrderBy() clause to use the desired property instead.

The projection/sort code would now look something like this:

```
// Projection (Yield the whole object, not just a property from it)
var projection = query.AsQueryable().Select(x => new Output()
{
  Parent1 = x.parent1,
  Parent2 = x.parent2,
  Instance = x.Items.First(y => y.numbers.item2 >= 230000)
});

// Sort and get results (Now just sort on the property we care about)
var result = projection.OrderBy(x => x.Instance.item2).ToList();
```